# How use fxaIgnore in TZFProcessFileFailureEvent

Tags: delphi, event-handling

How ignore error 00033? this error occurs because another process is using the file.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3c9n.png)
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arb5R.png)

It is possible to change the event handler so that when the error 00033 appears he ignore the file and jump to the next?

```
type TZFProcessFileFailureEvent = procedure ( 
Sender:    TObject; 
FileName:    String; 
Operation:    TZFProcessOperation; 
NativeError:   Integer; 
ErrorCode:    Integer; 
ErrorMessage:   String; 
var Action:   TZFAction 
) of object; 

type TZFAction = (fxaRetry, fxaIgnore, fxaAbort); 

property OnProcessFileFailure: TZFProcessFileFailureEvent;
```

my code for zip files...

```
var
  archiver : TZipForge;

begin
  // Create an instance of the TZipForge class
  archiver := TZipForge.Create(nil);
  try
  with archiver do
  begin
    // Set the name of the archive file we want to create
    FileName := 'C:\test.zip';
    // Because we create a new archive,
    // we set Mode to fmCreate
    OpenArchive(fmCreate);
    // Set base (default) directory for all archive operations
    BaseDir := 'C:\';
    // Add files to the archive by mask
    AddFiles('*.exe');
    CloseArchive();
  end;
  except
  on E: Exception do
    begin
      Writeln('Exception: ', E.Message);
      // Wait for the key to be pressed
      Readln;
    end;
  end;  
end.
```

Comment: Neither of your images was necessary. In any Delphi exception dialog, you can press Ctrl+C to copy the error message to the clipboard as text, and then paste it into your question here. Images should be used *only* when there is no other way to demonstrate the problem. [Here's a Meta SO post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/62576) listing the many reasons to avoid posting images.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know it was possible to copy the errors returned in the exception dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried adding code like this to your `OnProcessFileFailure` handler

```
if NativeError = 1033 then
  Action := fxaIgnore;
```

?

Even if you don't have documentation available for the zipping library you're using, the clue is in the fact that the `Action` parameter of the TZFProcessFileFailureEvent event is declared as a `var` parameter.  That means that any change to its value that you make inside the handler is passed back to the code that called the event handler, so that you can signal to it how you want it to react to the event occurring.

Btw, I'm not sure why you included your image1 in your q, because you have not asked about that.  If you want to know how to deal with a specific type of exception, like `EFOpenError` in an exception handler, look up how to do it in the Delphi online help.